# Flask - How to print different variables on the same page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to print out a list of entries, the total entry and the generated time in Flask. In my python code I have:

```
def stream_template(template_name, **context):
app.update_template_context(context)
t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
rv = t.stream(context)
return rv

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    # Dong something here to prepare for data
    total_entry = get_total_entry()
    generated_time = get_generated_time()
    entry_list = get_entry()
    def blog_entries():
        for entry in entry_list:
            yield entry
    return Response(stream_template('blog.html', data=blog_entries()))
```

I have my blog_entry() as: (for testing purpose)
    return [for i in range(5)]

In the blog.html I have: (for the purpose of testing, let's consider each entry as an int)

```
{% for i in data: %}
<br>Entry: {{ i }}</br>
{% endfor %}
```

As a result, I would get the list of all the entries. However, I would like to also have the total_entry and generated_time print out before and on the same page of printing out the entries. How should I change my python code and html template?

E.g: i want to have something like:

```
Total entry: 5
Generated time: 0.001
Entry: 1
Entry: 2
Entry: 3
Entry: 4
Entry: 5
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the variables as the `**context` keyword arguments. This should work but I haven't tested.

Here's the documentation for [stream_template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/).

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    # Dong something here to prepare for data
    def blog_entries():
        for entry in get_entry():
            yield entry
    return Response(stream_template('blog.html',
                                    data=blog_entries(),
                                    total_entries=get_total_entry(),
                                    gen_time=get_generated_time()))
```

The Jinja2 template. Changed the formatting to a list. You can access the `**context` keyword arguments in the Jinja2 -template by using the correct names.

```
<ul>
    <li>Total entries: {{ total_entries }}</li>
    <li>Generated time: {{ gen_time }}</li>
    {% for i in data: %}
    <li>Entry: {{ i }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi thank for your reply, i got the idea already but when i try to do that, it brings up the 500 internal server error. Problem come from "{% for i in data: %}" as the debuggers say "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". I didn't have that problem before :(

Comment: How does `get_entry` look like, please edit it to your question.

Comment: I think the problem is because of the stream_templates function given by Flask (on the website), it takes 1 argument while i'm sending 3 arguements at a time

Comment: Nope, `stream_template` takes one positional argument (`template_name` ) and any number of keyword arguments (`**context`).

Comment: I tested with blogentry = return[for i in range(1,5)], let me try to fix from my end. thank you

Comment: You can return `range(1, 5)` with out the `for` and the `[]`. Like so: `blogentry = range(1, 5)`